# Undefined attr() parameter

Tags: jquery, syntax, parameters, arguments, attr

[Here is my fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/Paulos3000/zssfkztx/)

This is a very basic question, I know, but looking at the JSFiddle above (taken straight from W3C website), I don't understand where the parameter/argument "origValue" argument (shown below) comes from, since it isn't defined anywhere - I would normally expect the function to be called with a defined argument in the space of this parameter.

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("#w3s").attr("href", function(i, origValue){
        return origValue + "/jquery"; 
    });
});
```

Obviously I know what it represents, but I don't know how the code understands that this is the original value. Can anyone explain?

Comment: This will help: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know how the code understands that this is the original value.

Because `attr`'s code calls that callback passing in the previous value. The *callback* doesn't know the value until `attr` calls it, telling it the value.

Let's take jQuery and `attr` out of the picture and just think of an array of objects and a function that lets you modify a property of each object using a callback:

```js
function updateProperty(array, propName, callback) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
        var obj = array[i];
        obj[propName] = callback(i, obj[propName]);
        //                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ This is how the callback knows
        //                                        the original value
    }
}

var objects = [
    {"color": "green"},
    {"color": "blue"},
    {"color": "red"}
];

console.log("Before: " + JSON.stringify(objects));
updateProperty(objects, "color", function(index, origValue) {
    return origValue.toUpperCase();
});
console.log("After : " + JSON.stringify(objects));
```

That can be implemented more efficiently or in less code, but the idea is to show exactly how the callback is getting the original value.

jQuery's `attr` does something very similar to `updateProperty` above.